# How can I make generated created record start at other value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code that creates several records, if my [OrderNr] is 1111 and my [Aantal] is 5.
It will create 5 records with [SerialNumber] like this: 111101, 111102, 111103, 11104, 111105.

I have another textbox named [Start], I want that to be the start number, so let's say I put in [OrderNr] 1111 and in [Aanta] 6 and in [Start] 13, then I want the [SerialNumber] to be: 111113, 111114, 11115, 111116, 11117, 111118. Is this possible?

```
Private Sub OpenForm_Click()
Dim strToTextBox As String
Dim strAantal As Integer
Dim intHowManyCopies As Integer
 strAantal = Me.Aantal

On Error Resume Next
intHowManyCopies = CInt(strAantal)
On Error GoTo 0

If intHowManyCopies <> 0 Then
    For intCopy = 1 To intHowManyCopies
        If intCopy < 10 Then
         strToTextBox = Me.OrderNr & "0" & CStr(intCopy)
        Else
         strToTextBox = Me.OrderNr & CStr(intCopy)
        End If
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Geleidelijst " & _
        "(SerialNmbr, InvoerOrderNr, InvoerAantal, InvoerSapArtNr, InvoerVermogen, LS1, InvoerSAPItemName, LS2, HS1, HS2) " & _
        "VALUES('" & strToTextBox & "','" & Me.OrderNr & "'," & Me.Aantal & ",'" & Me.SapArtNr & "','" & Me.Vermogen & "','" & Me.LS1 & "','" & Me.SAPItemName & "','" & Me.LS2 & "','" & Me.HS1 & "','" & Me.HS2 & "')"
    Next intCopy
End If
DoCmd.OpenForm "GeleidelijstForm"

DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acLast
Dim t1 As Long, i As Long
t1 = CLng(Nz(Me.Aantal, 1))
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acLast
For i = 1 To t1 - 1
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "GeleidelijstForm", acPrevious
Next i
DoCmd.Close acForm, "OrderinvoerForm"
Call Forms.GeleidelijstForm.PrintFrm_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not! Do the following changes in your code :

```
Dim intStart As Integer
intStart = CInt(Me.Start)
```

And modify your `For` loop `For intCopy = 1 To intHowManyCopies` to this :

```
For intCopy = intStart To intStart + intHowManyCopies - 1
```

Here, intStart = 13, so the `For` starts with 13 and loops through 18 (13+6-1)